# Popup Message on save click of partial view inside popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, popup, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Hi I'm working in MVC

i have a scenario as follows.

I have to display message popup on successfully saving data in partial view inside popup and clicking on the ok button of the success message popup, should close both the popup and should load my Main view![enter image description here][1]

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HXfQ2.png i have attached example pic here pls check this out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bootstrap or jQuery dialog for modal

try the following;

Say the first pop-up is **first-popup** and the second popup is **successPopup**, wire an event handler to the **click** event of the **Ok** button of the second popup with the following code.

```
function successPopup_onClose () {
   $('#first-popup').modal('hide');
   $('#successPopup').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: Hi i want to call the success popup on successfull save of the data's, like i have to redirect to same partialview in popup with the values persisting in it, with the success popup..

Comment: Ok, in that case, triggering of second popup should be based on the success status send by the server. I assume you are using Ajax to send the data back to server. in the $ajax call, wire up the success event, which will let your server code to pass a status value and for your client code to pick it up.